# giving a list of timezone from a country name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

is it possible that I can get a list of timezone given by a country name? for example if the country is "Canada" then I can get the list of its timezone?

Well, I am using this js script http://www.cssscript.com/generic-country-state-dropdown-list-countries-js/ for my dropdown of country and state, and I am planning that once a country is selected then its timezone also will be loaded as a dropdown to be select with?

The `country.js` returns the list of complete country name, so is it possible that I can get the timezone from a country name?

Comment: I don't think there's a native function for that. You need to create a list with all timezones per country (since timezones most often doesn't contain country names) in either JS or in PHP (which requires you to do an Ajax call to get the correct timezone).

Comment: [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) might be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some resources to your custom function which will do it.
You can start this way on list: https://timezonedb.com/time-zones